# Chrome extension: Options menu is disabled

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a new chrome extension and installed it in developers mode.It is working fine in my laptop. But in some other laptops, the options button is disabled. Please help.
I am unable to share the full code but this is how the manifest.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Asana Actual vs Estimation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Add tags to task if the actual hours exceeds the estimated value",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js":      ["js/jquery/jquery.js","js/content.js"],
    "css": ["css/styles.css"]

  }],
  "options_page":"options.html",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Can you put only manifest.json file? @ShashiGharti

Comment: Hi Moshe and Ghanshyam, I have shared the manifest file

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of this "options button"?

Answer (score 0):

Its working. This line was not there 
"options_page":"options.html" 
in manifest.json. Adding that line solved the problem.